# Could you please do X vs. Could you do X please

Tags: phrases, expressions, connotation

I'm an English teacher, and I heard a student say "could you please open the window" the other day.

To my ears, "could you please open the window" as a construction sounds exasperated, even irritated, whereas "could you open the window please" sounds polite and friendly.

If I sent an email saying

"could you please file the report by Thursday"

to me that construction almost carries an implicit:

"could you please file the report by Thursday, *not late like you usually do you jackass*"  or "could you please file the report by Thursday *and for God's sake don't make me ask you again*".  I'm exaggerating more than a little for effect of course, but my point is, it sounds a lot more insistent to me, whereas "Could you file the report by Thursday please" is simply a polite request.

I haven't been able to find anything on this, do people agree with me, or is this entirely in my head?

Comment: It all depends on tone of voice. The placement of *please* in a sentence has nothing to do with irritation. I suggest you're reading that into it.

Comment: It's *almost* entirely in your head. But the "distinction" you're making really just amounts to placing exaggerated stress on the word ***please***. In practice, the (optional) initial ***Could you*** is almost irrelevant. It has syntactic justification, but functionally it's not much more than throat-clearing to gain attention before delivering the *real* utterance - which "starts" with the exaggerated ***please***. As in many card games, you "lead with your strongest suit" - get the ***important*** word in ***first*** (or at least, ***early*** :)

Comment: (anything tacked on the end, like this comment or a final "please", looks like an afterthought)

Comment: Normal: "Please do not feed the bears." Irritated: "Please do *not* feed the bears." Apoplectic: "*Please do not feed the fucking bears!*"

Comment: @Robusto So would you not read any difference in subtext between "could you driver slower please" and "could you please drive slower"?  To me, the first is a request, while the second carries the implication that you should already know to drive slower.

Comment: I still think you're supposing that word order carries more semantic freight here than it really does. I can hear either of those as being neutral or aggressive, depending on the tone used.

Answer (score 3):

> Could you please open the window?  vs Could you open the window
>   please?

Let's take the spoken example first.

As a native English speaker (Bos-Wash corridor) with a bit of acting ability, I can make either sentence sound polite, impatient, irritated, peremptory or downright offensive.  I know, because I have been trying it out several times while doing yard work.  Fortunately, I was alone.

That being said, I found it easier to make "Could you open the window please" sound ingratiating and a bit easier to make "Could you please open the window" sound peremptory.

Others might disagree, having performed the same experiment.

My conclusion:  Possibly there was something in the attitude or intonation of the student that struck you as, I am guessing, peremptory.  If you are teaching ESL, this might arise from the culture of the students you are teaching.  Only you can decide that.

Considering the e-mail next:

"Hi, John:  Could you please file the report by Thursday" carries no "you jackass" implications for me.  If the e-mail had no salutation, both sentences sound a tad peremptory -- that you are too busy and important to waste time typing "Hi, John".

You asked if it was only in your head.  My answer: unless there is context you aren't telling us about in your Question, probably.

Comment: Could you add another email example, where the writer is in a supplicating position rather than supervisory?  Here's one, taken from an actual email I sent today to several people at my son's school: *Could someone please acknowledge that this has been received, and let me know what the plan is?*

Comment: Sounds like a real nailbiter! // The please sentence was followed by an informative one, and then of course, "Thank you!".

Answer (score 1):

Placement of 'please' in both the sentences is idiomatic English.

'Please' is used commonly at the end with a syntax as in the post in English to make a request more polite.

The same sintax with 'please' in the mid or front positions brings in a change in semantics meaning the request is serious or important and sometimes, sounds more like an order.Placed at the front/ mid position, it may seem that you are, in a sense, jogging the listeners/ readers elbow to be mindful— don't-forget-type!– a sense of desperation or urgent need. The defect that we find in the post is that it is strongly worded about the mid position of it. I agree with the spirit.

Now a days, 'please' can easily be misconstrued as an expression of frustration. We call it 'irrate please' or 'impolite please'. There is a growing tendency to avoid 'please' by making the sentence wordy. Above all syntax and semantic are eually important to make 'please' meaningful.

Comment: Tantalizing last paragraph.  Could you clean up the general sloppiness of your answer, and expand the last paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine.

> Could you please do X

is a construction I use often.  It trips off the tongue easily, which makes it sound casual, hence good for a classroom setting.

*I originally came by my English in the US (DC suburb), and currently live in upstate NY.*

Comment: background on where you're from/what's your first language?